# Error: yarn add @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest --non-interactive

Tags: npm, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, salesforce-communities

While Trying to install LWC local Server , getting this error then using this command
sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server

Tried applying all available community help but issue is still the same , tried restalling everything but no fix , please if someone can help then please help

This is the error Output :

Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.0
gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.0 found at "C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:369:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:390:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:420:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
gyp ERR! command "C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.180.0-d902059\bin\node.exe" "C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Local\sfdx\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Installing plugin @salesforce/lwc-dev-server... failed
Error: yarn add @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest --non-interactive
--mutex=file:C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Local\sfdx\yarn.lock
--preferred-cache-folder=C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Local\sfdx\yarn --check-files exited with code 1

```
LWC local server installation
```